# Chrome plugin to delete css class from website

Tags: css, google-chrome, plugins

I need a plugin to chrome which will remove provided class from body/html tag on specific webpage.

Example: my bank just changed it's website and I discovered that I just need to remove class 'lifting' from html and body tag to bring it's old look.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called "Stylus" which you can use to apply custom CSS. Thus you migth be able to override it.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne